# Xpath Expression to select nodes based on presence of child node?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to use Xpath to find all `<div>`s with a given CSS class (.product).

```
<div class="product">
    <a href="#product/1966740"><img class="cover_image" src="https://foobar.JPG" alt="foobar" title="foobar">
    <h3>foobar</h3></a>
    <div class="price">$66.00</div>
    <div class="rrp">$219.11</div>
</div>
```

So the Xpath to find those is relatively simple:

```
//div[@class="product"]
```

However, I only want to find those products that aren't sold out. Sold out products look like this:

```
<div class="product">
    <img class="availability" src="https://sold_out_tag.png" alt="sold out">
    <a href="#product/1963553"><img class="cover_image" src="foobar.jpg" alt="foobar" title="foobar">
    <h3>FooBar<h3></a>
    <div class="price">$40.00</div>
    <div class="rrp">$129.33</div>
</div>
```

I was thinking I can use not(), and check for `<div>`s that do not contain an `<img>` with the alt attribute set to "sold out".

However, the following isn't valid:

```
//div[@class="product" and not([img[@alt="sold out"]])]
```

Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You don't need `[]`s around the `img` sub-path:

```
//div[@class="product" and not(img[@alt = "sold out"])]
```

Another way to write essentially the same thing is:

```
//div[@class="product" and not(img/@alt = "sold out")]
```

Lastly, since `class` attributes can contain more than one class, it's often better to use `contains()` to check for classes:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), " product ") and not(img/@alt = "sold out")]
```

Comment: Cool, this one works! =) Question - you said I don't need the [] - how does XPath know that I'm asking it to check for the presence of child nodes? Secondly, what is with the concatenation of @class with spaces? Finally - any good guides you'd recommend to XPath?

Comment: (1) `not()` converts its contents to a boolean value before performing its evaluation. If those contents are a node-set expression, the boolean value will be `false` if the node-set is empty, and `true` if it is non-empty. (2) The spaces prevent false positives due to a partial match of a class name. For example, `contains('not-a-product', 'product')` will evaluate to `true`, while `concains(' not-a-product ', ' product ')` will evaluate to `false`, as desired. (3) The best advice I can give is to read the [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and practice, practice, practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath:

```
//div[@class="product" and not(img[@alt="sold out"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making a small mistake it should be

//div[@class="product"]/img [ @alt!="sold out"]