# Troubleshooting XPath Expression to select nodes based on child node

Tags: html, xpath

NB - This question is very similar to the other one I asked - [Xpath Expression to select nodes based on presence of child node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083952/xpath-expression-to-select-nodes-based-on-presence-of-child-node) - however, I'm trying to extend it, and failing.

I have a HTML page listing products.

I'm trying to use Xpath to distinguish between available and sold-out products.

Available products look like this:

```
<div class="product-widget-container">
    <article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" class="product grid_4 full space omega large " data-productid="1996364" data-name="Daily Wrinkle Defence Essential Skin Reviver Cream Cleanser - 100ml" data-actual-price="5.99" data-is-available="true" data-low-stock="" data-popularity="6" data-smallimgsrc="https://staging.foo.com.au/site_media/uploads/product_image/2014/1/16/pd1996364_94d4a520-7e4a-11e3-930f-000c29c9a057_image_310x434.JPG" data-largeimgsrc="https://staging.foo.com.au/site_media/uploads/product_image/2014/1/16/pd1996364_94d4a520-7e4a-11e3-930f-000c29c9a057_image_310x434.JPG" data-sizes="[]" data-available-sizes="[]" data-categories="[119977]" data-brand="That Natural Source" data-discount="83" data-default-order="9">
        <figure>
            <div class="product-img-container ">
            <img itemprop="image" class="lazy product-img" src="https://staging.foo.com.au/site_media/uploads/product_image/2014/1/16/pd1996364_94d4a520-7e4a-11e3-930f-000c29c9a057_image_310x434.JPG" data-original="https://staging.foo.com.au/site_media/uploads/product_image/2014/1/16/pd1996364_94d4a520-7e4a-11e3-930f-000c29c9a057_image_310x434.JPG" alt="Up to 85% off Summer Looks Daily Wrinkle Defence Essential Skin Reviver Cream Cleanser - 100ml " style="display: inline;">
            <span class="arrow arrow-up"></span>
            <div class="quick-buy" style="display: none;">
            <span class="arrow-down-trans"></span>
            <div class="select-size">
            <form class="express-buy" action="/basket/add/1996364/" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_quantity_1996364" class="purchase-quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="addbasket.x">
            <span>
            <input class="add-to-basket btn btn-primary  btn-large " type="submit" value="ADD TO BASKET">
            </span>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <a itemprop="url" class="overlay-link" href="/event/outlet/up-to-off-summer-looks/1996364-daily-wrinkle-defence-essential-skin-reviver-cream-cleanser-100ml/" title="Daily Wrinkle Defence Essential Skin Reviver Cream Cleanser - 100ml"></a>
            <figcaption>
            <h2 itemprop="name" class="mason name">
            That Natural Source: Daily Wrinkle Defence Essential Skin Reviver Cream Cleanser - 100ml
            </h2>
            <small itemprop="brand" class="bed"> Up to 85% off Summer Looks</small>
            <small class="bed shoes-price">
            $5.99
            <del>$34.95 RRP</del>
            <span class="discount">(83% discount)</span>
            </small>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </article>
</div>
```

Sold-out products look like this:

```
<div class="product-widget-container">
    <article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" class="product grid_4 full space omega large " data-productid="1996526" data-name="#T58 When Monkeys Fly! - Oz The Great And Powerful Collection By OPI" data-actual-price="10.99" data-is-available="" data-low-stock="true" data-popularity="1" data-smallimgsrc="https://staging.foo.com.au/site_media/uploads/product_image/2014/1/16/pd1996526_d0402efe-7e4a-11e3-930f-000c29c9a057_image_310x434.jpg" data-largeimgsrc="https://staging.foo.com.au/site_media/uploads/product_image/2014/1/16/pd1996526_d0402efe-7e4a-11e3-930f-000c29c9a057_image_310x434.jpg" data-sizes="[]" data-available-sizes="[]" data-categories="[119968]" data-brand="OPI" data-discount="0" data-default-order="39">
        <div class="stock-status be_sprites sold-out">Sold Out</div>
        <figure>
            <div class="product-img-container ">
            <img itemprop="image" class="lazy product-img" src="https://staging.foo.com.au/site_media/uploads/product_image/2014/1/16/pd1996526_d0402efe-7e4a-11e3-930f-000c29c9a057_image_310x434.jpg" data-original="https://staging.foo.com.au/site_media/uploads/product_image/2014/1/16/pd1996526_d0402efe-7e4a-11e3-930f-000c29c9a057_image_310x434.jpg" alt="Up to 85% off Summer Looks #T58 When Monkeys Fly! - Oz The Great And Powerful Collection By OPI " style="display: inline;">
            <span class="arrow arrow-up"></span>
            </div>
            <a itemprop="url" class="overlay-link" href="/event/outlet/up-to-off-summer-looks/1996526-t58-when-monkeys-fly-oz-the-great-and-powerful-collection-by-opi/" title="#T58 When Monkeys Fly! - Oz The Great And Powerful Collection By OPI"></a>
            <figcaption>
            <h2 itemprop="name" class="mason name">
            Opi: #T58 When Monkeys Fly! - Oz The Great And Powerful Collection By OPI
            </h2>
            <small itemprop="brand" class="bed"> Up to 85% off Summer Looks</small>
            <small class="bed shoes-price">
            $10.99
            </small>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </article>
</div>
```

I was thinking I can go on either the "sold-out" class on the , or the `Sold Out` text within it.

I've tried all of the following, and none of them seem to work - they all give me the full set of products:

```
//div[@class="product-widget-container" and not(div[@class="stock-status be_sprites sold-out"])]

//div[@class="product-widget-container" and not(div[contains(@class, "sold-out")])]

//div[@class="product-widget-container" and not(div[contains(., "Sold Out")])]
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong in my XPath expression?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expressions have the right idea, but you don't need to nest `[ ]` brackets. Once you open them, you are in a conditional statement: everything you write will be part of the statement. So when you want to check an attribute of a child node, you just need to select it: `node[child/@attribute]`.

You also need to check for the `div` at any depth since it isn't the first child node. If you write `div[div/@class="foo"]`, you are checking for `<div><div class="foo"></div></div>`. If you write `div[.//div/@class="foo"]`, you are checking for `<div><anything><bar><div class="foo"></div></bar></anything></div>`.

Something like

```
//div[@class="product-widget-container" and not(.//div/@class="stock-status be_sprites sold-out")]
```

should work !

Answer (score 0):

try

```
//div[@class='product-widget-container' and not(@class='stock-status be_sprites sold-out')]
```

you should remove `div[` and `]` in the predicate